# Working with arrays passed as parameters in assembly function

Tags: arrays, x86, masm

I'm trying to write a function in assembly to perform a bubble sort. I'm passing a pointer to an array as a parameter and trying to operate upon it to sort the array. I need to compare two values within the array, but when I try to I get "error A2026:constant expected". The error appears in the following lines:

```
mov ecx, [arr + pos2 * 4]
cmp [arr + pos * 4], ecx
```

I am using x86 and MASM (Intel syntax).

Comment: It's not clear what syntax you are using. MASM uses Intel syntax.

Comment: This is not MASM Intel syntax. Still unclear.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure what the correct syntax is. That could be my problem afterall.

Comment: You can read the manual to see what the correct syntax is. oh look, you edited the question and changed the syntax. It's still wrong, but for a different reason. You need to read the manual to see what addressing modes are permitted.

Comment: I'm doing my best here, these are all things that I've seen on the internet/learned in class. I understand that I need to research things on my own and I am very willing to do that, I guess I just don't really know where to find this information.

Comment: For this to work you will need to place the address of `pos2` into a register, and the address of `pos` in a register. Then you will have to use those registers in the addressing. Scaling doesn't operate on an address value it can only scale the value in a register.

Comment: try `mov esi, offset pos2` `mov edi, offset pos` `mov ecx, [arr + esi * 4]` `cmp [arr + edi * 4], ecx` (_esi_ and _edi_ can be any of the available general purpose registers

Comment: You have to use registers in addressing modes, not values in memory.  `pos*4` is the problem.  (You can use the base address of the array directly, though, as an assemble-time constant.)  I think this is a duplicate of [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](//stackoverflow.com/q/34058101), but maybe there's a more specific Q&A about MASM syntax.